# delete shallow's copy object and the origin object

Tags: c++, delete-operator, shallow-copy

I have a class vector with the attributes:

```
class Vector
{
    private:
        int _capacity;
        int _size; 
        int _resizeFactor; 
        int* _elements;
```

with this method:

```
Vector::Vector(const Vector& other)
{
    this->_size = other._size;
    this->_capacity = other._capacity;
    this->_resizeFactor = other._resizeFactor;
    delete[] this->_elements;
    this->_elements = other._elements;
}
```

and this destructor:

```
Vector::~Vector()
{
    if (this->_elements) 
        delete[] this->_elements;
    this->_elements = NULL;
}
```

after declaring on object, inserting array to it and copy it, in the end of the program, there is an error:

> 1.exe has triggered a breakpoint.
>
> that points to the line:
>
> ```
>    delete[] this->_elements;
> ```
>
> in the destructor.

how can I cancel the destruction of only 1 of the objects?
**without changing the attributes type**

Comment: have you considered using `std::shared_ptr` ?

Comment: Why are you using `this->`

Comment: if i understand correctly, its having no effect

Comment: This line `this->_elements = other._elements;` makes both vectors point to the same data. In their destructors they will both try to `delete[]` the same elements.

Comment: A constructor is not supposed to destroy anything. `delete` shouldn't be there. You haven't even initialised `_elements`, much less allocated anything for it to point to.

Comment: @ArashMohammadi i need to use the template that I gave for the classes attributes

Comment: All those explicit `this->` dereferences are pointless. The `if` statement in `if (this->_elements) 
        delete[] this->_elements;` is pointless. Setting `this->_elements` to `NULL` in the destructor is pointless (and besides, you should be using `nullptr` rather than `NULL`).

Comment: @molbdnilo its destructor, not contractor

Comment: And why implement `Vector` when there is already a `std::vector` which can be used with `std::shared_ptr` if you need to share objects... Those librairies were made by expert and given how many problems you have in the above code, you should definitively use those instead of rolling your own.

Comment: What is an **attribute type**? Obviously, you cannot cancel the destruction of an object without making radical changes to your `Vector` class. In a language like C++, you have to do your own tracking of references or use librairies that do it for you. And you also need to properly define your copy/move constructors and assignment operators.

Comment: @arik I was referring to your copy constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to either make a deep copy or implement something along the line of reference counting and only delete `elements` when the last instance of a `Vector` that references the same data is deleted.

In your copy constructor you should not `delete` anything, because at the point where you call

```
delete[] this->_elements;
```

`elements` is not yet pointing to anything. It is the job of the constructor to allocate the memory (or if you really wish make it point to `other->elements`).

Answer (score 1):

First, the `delete[] this->_elements;` seems pointless since `this->_elements` has not been initialized yet in the copy constructor.

To implement shallow copy, you need to use reference count to keep record of how many objects are referencing the data so that you don't delete the same array twice (like what you do in your code now).

I recommend using `std::shared_ptr` which has already implemented reference count for you. To do so, replace int* with `std::shared_ptr<int>`. Notice that `std::shared_ptr` doesn't automatically support array so you will need to supply a custom deleter by yourself: `this->_elements=std::shared_ptr<int> (new int[100], [](int *p){delete[] p;});`. Then, `std::shared_ptr` will handle memory management for you.

Comment: thank for the answer but my task it's to do it with this template:
class Vector
{
    private:
        int _capacity;
        int _size; 
        int _resizeFactor; 
        int* _elements;

Comment: @arik then you have to implement your own reference count. It's basically just increasing the count when copying and decreasing it in deconstructor. Remember to use atomic or mutex to avoid problems in multi-thread situation. As far as I know, you can't implement shallow copy without using reference count.

Comment: And also use `std::vector` which does many things your are trying to do in your own `Vector`.